# unloading dynamically declared class in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a class defined using theClass.class_eval and Object.const_set(className, theClass).
Is there any way to remove the definition of this class?
During testing I need to load different versions of the same class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Object.send(:remove_const, className) did the trick.