# How to require file as part of a module in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, module, namespaces

I have a file `SomethingClass.rb` which looks as follows:

```
class SomethingClass
  def initialize
    puts "Hello World"
  end
end
```

I would like to `require` the file `SomethingClass.rb`, and make `SomethingClass` part of the module `SomethingModule` **without** changing the file.

Also, I would like to avoid making `SomethingClass` part of the namespace outside of that module at all. In other words, I want to `require` the file and the rest of my application should not change apart from the fact that `SomethingModule` will be defined.

This does not work (I assume because `require` is executed in `Kernel` scope):

```
module SomethingModule
  require './SomethingClass.rb'
end
```

Is this possible in Ruby?

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood the question, this doesn't seem to have anything do with a file containing a class definition being required in another file. Suppose you have one file that defines one class and one module (not a class within the module). I believe you wish to move the class to within the module without changing the class definition. Is that correct? If so, is that the essence of the question?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, that is correct. I asked the question with `require` because this is the way I intended to use it in. I wasn't sure whether the use of `require` could make solutions possible other than moving a class to a module.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your class file, from what I've gathered, there are only kind of hacky ways to do this - see [Load Ruby gem into a user-defined namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762547/load-ruby-gem-into-a-user-defined-namespace) and [How to undefine class in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503558/how-to-undefine-class-in-ruby).

However I think if you allow yourself to modify the class file, it is a little easier. Probably the simplest thing to do would be to set the original class name to something that will surely have no name conflict, e.g.:

```
class PrivateSomethingClass
  def initialize
    puts "Hello World"
  end
end

module SomethingModule
  SomethingClass = PrivateSomethingClass
end
```

Now you have `SomethingModule::SomethingClass` defined but not `SomethingClass` on the global namespace.

Another way to do it would be to use a factory method and [anonymous class](https://pbrisbin.com/posts/anonymous_classes_in_ruby/):

```
class SomethingClassFactory
  def self.build
    Class.new do
      def initialize
        "hello world"
      end
    end
  end
end

module SomethingModule
  SomethingClass = SomethingClassFactory.build
end
```